# Groovy findAll and each tag question

Tags: grails, groovy, each, gsp, findall

I have the following domain classes:

```
class User = {
       String username
       ... 
       Company company
 }

class Company {
    String name
    ...
}
```

That is, there is a n:1 relationship between user and company.
These classes are so and I cannot change them.

At the show.gsp I want to have the details of the company together with links to 
the users who belongs to this company.

I know that I can achieve this writing an own tag, but I am sure that this would be possible using the **each** tag or the the **findAll** tag.

If I do the following

```
<g:each in="${User.findAll('from User order by username')}" var="userInstance">
    <li><g:link controller="role" action="show"
         id="${userInstance.id}">${userInstance.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link>
   </li>
</g:each>
```

I've tried to pass the **${companyInstance}** as a parameter but either I got an exception or it didn't work.

I've also tried using **User.findAllByCompany**.

When using:

```
<g:findAll in="${user}" expr="it.company == ${companyInstance}  ">
```

I am getting an empty set.

Is there an easy way to achieve this without writing a taglib?

Thanks in advance.

Luis

Comment: You mention that there is a n:1 relationship, but in your Company class, you don't refer to a list (or set) of User. Is that normal?
Currently I can only see a 1:1 "belongsTo" relationship.

Comment: True. Actually it is enough for what I am trying to do. The company_id is a foreign key at the table User..
Anyway the question is applies in general: How to pass a parameter to the findAll tag resp. each tag. Thanks for your remark (+1 for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<g:findAll>` tag iterates over an object list but it does not query the DB as done with `User.findAll(..)`

The correct code is:

```
<g:each in="${User.findAll('from User as u where u.company=:company order by username', [company: companyInstance])}" var="userInstance">
    <li><g:link controller="role" action="show"
         id="${userInstance.id}">${userInstance.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link>
   </li>
</g:each>
```

If you absolutely want to use g:findAll, then you first need to build the list of users as following:

```
<% def users = User.listOrderByUsername()%>
<g:findAll in="${users}" expr="it.company == ${companyInstance}  ">
```

I hope it helps,

Regards,

Fabien.

Answer (score -1):

It's more simple that you think: `${userInstance.company.encodeAsHTML()}`

Comment: I think I was ot clear enough. I am at company view. I mean, I don't have the userInstance. I have the companyInstance.